# Web application to manage user subscriptions and account renewals

Tags: web-apps, user-management

I am looking for a web application to help me manage user subscriptions and account renewals. I also need to be able to upload files that my subscribers can download only if their respective accounts are active.

So basically an entirely independent app "just for book-keeping" – not something that automatically controls other components (except for the mentioned downloads which it should offer itself). We need to maintain a list of our clients (subscribers to our services) and based on the account status, allow or deny access to files, and will do our work manually from there, comparing its contents with the services.

If there is a FOSS alternative to accomplish this goal, the better. Otherwise, freeware or paid options are also acceptable.

Any ideas will be more than welcome, especially if you have used the application or framework and can briefly share your own experience with it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I've integrated that with your question – please check if I got that right. And feel free to [edit] anytime :) Good luck!